# get the proof of theorem using natural deduction

Tags: propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I want to show, using natural deduction:

$$[(p \land r) \lor (p \land s) \lor (q \land r) \lor (q \land s)] \to [(p \lor q) \land (r \lor s)]$$

I get this:
[image: I get this]

but I don't know what should I assume. I tried to assume $\lnot(p \lor q)$, and then assume $p$ and $r$ particularly, but contradiction wasn't reached((( idk what is wrong.

Comment: I won't answer because I'm not an expert on ND, but prove the first two disjuncts imply $p\land(r\lor s)$ and the last two imply $q\land(r\lor s)$; and, disjoining these, prove $(p\lor q)\land(r\lor s)$. Alternatively, since $a\to b$ is equivalent to $\neg b\to\neg a$, you need only check $[(\neg p\land \neg q)\lor(\neg r\land \neg s)]\to[(\neg p\lor\neg r)\land(\neg p\lor\neg s)\land(\neg q\lor\neg r)\land(\neg q\lor\neg s)]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $\lor$-E as in the other question you posted. Show that each of the conjuncts $p \land r$, $p \land s$ etc, implies the right hand side $(p\lor q)\land (r \lor s)$ and then you're done.

Lemma: the following derivation is valid (generalisation of $\lor$-E to $4$ conjuncts).

1. $(\phi_1 \lor \phi_2 \lor \phi_3 \lor \phi_3)$ ass.
2. We show $\phi_1 \to \psi$.
3. We show $\phi_2 \to \psi$.
4. We show $\phi_3 \to \psi$.
5. We show $\phi_4 \to \psi$.
6. $\psi$ follows.
7. $(\phi_1 \lor \phi_2 \lor \phi_3 \lor \phi_3) \to \psi$ by intro $\to$.

Try to show it by reducing to the usual $\lor$-E rule.

And that $p \land r \to (p\lor q)\land (r \lor s)$ holds, as an example:

1. $p \land r$. (ass)
2. $p$ from $\land$-E on 1.
3. $r$ from $\land$-E on 1.
4. $p \lor q$ from $\lor$-I on 2.
5. $r \lor s$ from $\lor$-I on 3.
6. $(p\lor q)\land (r \lor s)$ from 4,5.
7. $(p \land r) \to (p\lor q)\land (r \lor s)$ from intro $\to$, drop 1.

And so on for the other three terms.

Comment: thank, but can you explain, please, how did you get s in 3 step from the first one?

Comment: @GERI typo, I meant $r$; corrected.

Comment: ♥ ❤ ღ ❦ ❥❣ wow, thank you so much

Comment: is 7 step necessary?? just can't get this.

Comment: @GERI We want 2 to 5 of the lemma so yes we need an implication. Or do you have another $\lor$-E rule?

Comment: ooh, everything is ok, sorry

Comment: https://wampi.ru/image/6tYmkdr I wrote the whole solution, please check it

Comment: @GERI where do the negations get into it? You don’t need those. I’d mark it as wrong.

Comment: @GERI Indeed, use *conditional introduction* after each of the four subproofs, and *negation introduction* after that.  The basic idea is that *Each of the four cases in the* first assumption *leads to a contradiction of the* second assumption, *therefore we deduce that the* second assumption *must be negated under the first.*"

Comment: $$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\tiny\fitch{}{\fitch{(p \land r)\lor(p\land s)\lor(q\land r)\lor(q\land s)}{\fitch{\neg[(p\lor q)\land(r\lor s)]}{\fitch{(p\land r)}{\vdots\\(p\lor q)\land(r\lor s)}\\(p\land r)\to[(p\lor q)\land(r\lor s)]\\\vdots\\(p\land s)\to[(p\lor q)\land(r\lor s)]\\\vdots\\(q\land r)\to[(p\lor q)\land(r\lor s)]\\\vdots\\(q\land s)\to[(p\lor q)\land(r\lor s)]\\(p\lor q)\land (r\lor s)\\\bot}\\\neg\neg[(p\lor q)\land(r\lor s)]\\ [(p\lor q)\land(r\lor s)]}\\ [(p\land r)\lor(p\land s)\lor(q\land r)\lor(q\land s)]\to[(p\lor q)\land(r\lor s)]}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp you don’t need negation or proofs from contradiction for this proof.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Well, indeed, it looks like you can just do a direct disjunction elimination.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  contradiction between [(p ∨ q) ∧ (r ∨ s)] (8 step) and ¬[(p ∨ q) ∧ (r ∨ s) (2 step), so we should get negation intro

Comment: @GrahamKemp don't we have to introduce the negation of the last assumption after we have received the contradiction?

Comment: @GERI what’s with the fetish with contradictions ?

Comment: @GERI No. As HennoBrandsma points out, the RAA is unnecessary, because we can derive it *directly*.$$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\tiny\fitch{}{\fitch{(p\land r)\lor(p\land s)\lor(q\land r)\lor(q\land s)}{\fitch{(p\land r)}{~~\vdots\\(p\lor q)\land(r\lor s)}\\(p\land r)\to[(p\lor q)\land(r\lor s)]\\~~\vdots\\(p\land s)\to[(p\lor q)\land(r\lor s)]\\~~\vdots\\(q\land r)\to[(p\lor q)\land(r\lor s)]\\~~\vdots\\(q\land s)\to[(p\lor q)\land(r\lor s)]\\(p\lor q)\land(r\lor s)}\\ [(p\land r)\lor(p\land s)\lor(q\land r)\lor(q\land s)]\to[(p\lor q)\land(r\lor s)]}$$